# SQL ORDER BY with column number or aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I've got 2 different results when I try `ORDER BY` with column number and with an aggregate function. What is the difference between these 2 methods? ( I thought they'd have the same output)

> List the 1978 films by order of cast list size. There're 3 tables below:

```
movie(id, title, yr, director)  
actor(id, name)  
casting(movieid, actorid, ord)
```

> Answer 1 using ORDER BY with column number:

```
SELECT title
       ,COUNT(a.id)  
FROM   movie m
       ,casting c
       ,actor a  
WHERE  m.id=movieid 
AND    a.id=actorid 
AND    yr=1978  
GROUP BY title  
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Using `COUNT(a.id)`. Everything is the same except the last line

```
...  
ORDER BY COUNT(a.id) DESC
```

Comment: I would find that hard to believe. Can you post both queries with both their outputs without changing or leaving something out?

Comment: It should be the same output except for when you have ties between rows. With ties the order can be different between each execution. Add title as a second order by column to get a persistent sort order with ties.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - If this is MySQL, sure.  But it's vendor specific behaviour.  In MS SQL Server, for example, the first is ordering by the scalar constant `2`, and has nothign to do with *field 2*.

Comment: @Dems - You are probably right about vendor specific but both MySQL and MS SQL Server orders by the second column in the output when you do `ORDER BY 2`. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx). "...specified as a name or column alias, or a nonnegative integer..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to make a subquery and order that for the clean result

Answer (score 0):

I think Jester has it.  Here's an example for you:

```
select title, actor_count from (
    SELECT title
       ,COUNT(a.id) actor_count 
    FROM   movie m
       ,casting c
       ,actor a  
    WHERE  m.id=movieid 
    AND    a.id=actorid 
    AND    yr=1978  
    GROUP BY title) subquery
order by actor_count
```